# I want to do join query from 2 different table and i want output from both table

Tags: php, mysql, database, join, outer-join

I apply **LEFT JOIN** and **RIGHT JOIN** query to get output from both table..

There is two table :

1st table for Product_list.. This table contain category_id which is foreign key and all other product detail..

[image]

2nd table for product_images.. This table contain product_id which is foreign key and product images separately..

[image]

I want product detail and product images for particular category_id..

I use this Query but not work properly :

```
SELECT * 
FROM product_list
LEFT JOIN product_images ON product_list.pro_id = product_images.pro_id
WHERE product_list.cat_id =  '.$id.'
UNION 
SELECT * 
FROM product_list
RIGHT JOIN product_images ON product_list.pro_id = product_images.pro_id
```

I get this output: 
[image]

API Code

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);

$response = array();

require_once __DIR__ . '/db_Connect.php';

// check for post data
if (isset($_GET["cat_id"])) {

    $id = $_GET['cat_id'];

    // get a product from products table
    //$q="SELECT * FROM product_list WHERE cat_id ='".$id."' ORDER BY pro_id DESC ";
    $q="SELECT * 
FROM product_list
LEFT JOIN product_images ON product_list.pro_id = product_images.pro_id
WHERE product_list.cat_id =  '.$id.'
UNION 
SELECT * 
FROM product_list
RIGHT JOIN product_images ON product_list.pro_id = product_images.pro_id WHERE product_list.cat_id =  '.$id.'";
    //print($q);
    $res = mysql_query($q);
    print($res);
    //exit();
    if (mysql_num_rows($res) > 0) {

        $responce["category_sub_list"]=array();

        // check for empty result
        while($result = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {

        $product=array();
        $product['pro_id']=$result['pro_id'];
        $product['cat_id']=$result['cat_id'];  
        $product['product_name']=$result['product_name'];
        $product['image']="http://friendzfashionz.com/pandora/admin/Sub_uploads/".$result['image'];
        $product['product_desc']=$result['product_desc'];

        array_push($responce["category_sub_list"],$product);
        } 
         $responce["success"]=1;
         echo json_encode($responce);

    } else {
        // no product found
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "No user found";

        // echo no users JSON
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
} else {
    // required field is missing
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

Comment: What is your current output and what is your expected output? Can you please post here?

Comment: Last photo in question is of current output @SmitRaval

Comment: Can you please try the query I have posted in answer?

Comment: it works in php myadmin properly but it didn't work in my API...@SmitRaval

Comment: Pleas update your question with all code so I can help you.

Comment: I post my API Code @SmitRaval

Comment: echo  this "SELECT * 
FROM product_list
LEFT JOIN product_images ON product_list.pro_id = product_images.pro_id
WHERE product_list.cat_id =  '.$id.'
UNION 
SELECT * 
FROM product_list
RIGHT JOIN product_images ON product_list.pro_id = product_images.pro_id WHERE product_list.cat_id =  '.$id.'" and run the query in phpmyadmin, check if it works or not?

Comment: its work in phpmyadmin....it gives proper output in phpmyadmin but it didn't work in my API..@SmitRaval

Comment: What is the query you are trying?

Comment: i tried your provided query@SmitRaval

Comment: No show me the final query after echoing $q. Smjya?

Comment: SELECT * 
FROM product_list
LEFT JOIN product_images ON product_list.pro_id = product_images.pro_id
WHERE product_list.cat_id =  '6'
UNION 
SELECT * 
FROM product_list
RIGHT JOIN product_images ON product_list.pro_id = product_images.pro_id
WHERE product_list.cat_id =  '6'  @SmitRaval

Comment: Remove '' from id.In your query put product_list.cat_id=".$id." in first query and in second query product_list.cat_id=".$id;

Comment: it didn't work...@SmitRaval

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166955/discussion-between-smit-raval-and-bhoomi-patel).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this query. You need to apply where condition in both queries.

```
SELECT * 
FROM product_list
LEFT JOIN product_images ON product_list.pro_id = product_images.pro_id
WHERE product_list.cat_id =  '.$id.'
UNION 
SELECT * 
FROM product_list
RIGHT JOIN product_images ON product_list.pro_id = product_images.pro_id WHERE product_list.cat_id =  '.$id.'
```